# Можно ли использовать слово "категорически" во фразе "надо категорически думать о..."?

Tags: словоупотребление

Можно ли использовать слово "категорически" во фразе

> Надо категорически думать о смене поставщика.

В том смысле, что это должно выражать бескомпромиссность предложения, что бездействию не может быть оправдания?

**UPDATE:** @Taosique заметил, что вышеупомянутая фраза звучит косно. Возможно, более корректная, хотя смысл несколько другой ("менять"/"думать о смене", хотя как можно менять и не подумать...):

> Категорически надо менять поставщика.

или ещё такой вариант:

> Категорически надо думать о смене поставщика.

Comment: Довольно косно звучит. Как будто "я вас категорически приветствую" у Гоблина.

Comment: @Taosique, я бы сказал "категорически" добавляет негативный оттенок текущему положению вещей, что оно категорически не устраивает говорящего. "От этого категорически надо отходить", "Натянул надоевшее нубовское тряпьё, нет, категорически надо от него избавляться!". А вот насчёт косности... Возможно, сделал обновление вопроса

Comment: Вторая фраза возможна, в отличие от первой (нельзя "категорически думать"), но в ней явный стилистический диссонанс между изысканным "категорически" и просторечным "надо", лучше выглядит "категорически необходимо...". Кстати, почему было не задать этот вопрос в русскоязычном разделе форума ( https://russian.stackexchange.com/ )?

Comment: @Alex_ander, спасибо. Очень ценное замечания о стилях. Кстати, я и задал вопрос на russian.stackexchange.com

Comment: Я не ту ссылку оставил, имел в виду часть форума, где всё обсуждение идёт на русском: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: А что подразумевается под "думать о смене поставщика"?  Сидеть на стуле и думать, как хорошо бы сменить поставщика?  Время от времени подумывать "надо бы сменить поставщика"?

Comment: @user31264, совершенно согласен, нагруженная и не фокусирующая внимание на сути конструкция. Лаконичный и точный вариант "Решительно/определённо надо менять поставщика"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что нет. Посмотрел в Корпусе последние по времени 140 вхождений слова `категорически`.  `Категорически думать`, или `категорически намереваться`, или чего-то эквивалентного по смыслу там нет.  Категорически можно: запрещать, отказываться, отвергать, требовать, быть против кого-либо или чего-либо. Также слово "категорически" часто употребляется с частицей или приставкой не, и один раз со словом `нет`: `здесь что-то категорически не так`, `она категорически не умела` и т. д.

Изредка встречаются выражения, противоположные перечисленным: `категорически одобряю`, `категорически за`.

В целом картина вырисовывается вот какая. Категорическими бывают: отношение к чему-то (отрицательное или, гораздо реже, положительное); выражение этого отношения (`категорически отрицаю`); императивы (требования, запреты); что-то отрицательное (`категорически не умела`, `категорически не так`).  Действия, кроме перечисленных, категорическими не бывают.

Comment: Кстати, встретил такой вариант употребления "Категорически поздравляю с (чем-либо)", звучит странно, по мне так даже неуместно, но в живом языке есть

Answer (score 3):

Поиск в корпусе русского языка показывает, что и комбинация ["Категорически + надо + глагол"](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%ED%E0%E4%EE&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%EA%E0%F2%E5%E3%EE%F0%E8%F7%E5%F1%EA%E8&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=1&lex3=&gramm3=V&sem3=&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2&flags3=&m3=), и комбинация ["Надо + категорически + глагол"](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%EA%E0%F2%E5%E3%EE%F0%E8%F7%E5%F1%EA%E8&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%ED%E0%E4%EE&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=1&lex3=&gramm3=V&sem3=&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2&flags3=&m3=) используются крайне редко.

Гораздо более популярны структуры использующие синонимы слова "категорически": "решительно", "безусловно". Я бы лично заменил "категорически" одним из синонимов.

Comment: Ещё "определённо"